# Convert JSON object containing objects into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, javascript-objects

My data is currently stored in this format, stored in a JSON file:

```
{
    "name": {
        "0": ______,
        "1": ______,
        "2": ______
    },
    "xcoord": {
        "0": ______,
        "1": ______,
        "2": ______
    },
    "ycoord": {
        "0": ______,
        "1": ______,
        "2": ______
    }
}
```

And I need to convert it into this format, as an array of objects:

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": _____,  
        "xcoord": _____,
        "ycoord": _____
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": _____,
        "xcoord": _____,
        "ycoord": _____
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": _____,
        "xcoord": _____,
        "ycoord": _____
    }
]
```

As you can see, I also need to take the number keys in my first data format and make them the "id" values in my second data format. (Since the position of the object in the array and the id number match up, maybe that would be another way to create the "id" key?) I would then store my second data format into a local variable to use in my JS code.

Any ideas on how I can do this? I'm not very good with restructuring this kind of data.

Comment: Create an array, then iterate the JSON object and for each sub-property check if there's already an element in the array. If not create it. Then add the parent property with the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done for instance with two imbricated `.forEach()`:

```js
var obj = {
    "name": {
        0: 'name0',
        1: 'name1',
        2: 'name2'
    },
    "xcoord": {
        0: 'xcoord0',
        1: 'xcoord1',
        2: 'xcoord2'
    },
    "ycoord": {
        0: 'ycoord0',
        1: 'ycoord1',
        2: 'ycoord2'
    }
};

var res = [];

Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
  Object.keys(obj[k]).forEach(v => {
    (res[v] = (res[v] || { id: v }))[k] = obj[k][v];
  });
});

console.log(res);
```

**Note**:

This line ...

```
(res[v] = (res[v] || { id: v }))[k] = obj[k][v]
```

... is a short way to do:

```
if(!res[v]) {
  // if this record doesn't exist yet,
  // create it with its implied 'id' property
  res[v] = { id: v };
}
// add property 'k' to this record
res[v][k] = obj[k][v];
```